# Is rooting 4.2.2 really this complicated?

Tags: rooting, nexus-4

On 4.2 (or was it 4.1?) it was really just a few keypresses in the Nexus 4 Toolkit, or downloading a simple app. With the current version 4.2.2 however, rooting has become a huge task, apparently.

I've been trying to root my Nexus 4 (running 4.2.2) but the Nexus 4 Toolkit says it's `offline`. From my searches it turns out that 4.2.2 has extra "security" that makes this harder than it used to be. I'm not a developer but there's something about telling my phone that the PC that wants to root it is trusted.

I found [this 14-step guide](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/articles/435631/20130215/nexus4-root-android422-jdq39-jellybean-install-cwmrecovery.htm) in which I am asked to install a developer toolkit, install Eclipse, and a few other things. My impression is that this is like shooting sparrows with cannonballs.

**Is it really this difficult, or am I totally missing the goal here?**

Answer (score 1):

My further investigation indicates that the *Nexus 4 Toolkit* isn't the best one to use - in fact it doesn't seem to work at all with 4.2.2.

Instead, the **[Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/)** seems to work well with 4.2.2 and is basically a one-click installer. Download from the linked page and run it; it will do the rest by itself and/or give you simple instructions when needed.

Update: I've just completed the rooting process with this tool. Worked well and was simple enough. Note that after completing the process, I had to download and install the `Superuser` app from the Play Store - this step was not completely evident, but simple to do.